# Conceptual meaning of generalized Kloosterman sums for cuspidal representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, supercuspidal-representations

Piatetski-Shapiro, in §13 of his book on complex representations of $GL_2(\mathbf F_q)$, constructs cuspidal representations out of non-decomposable characters $\nu: L^\times \to \mathbf C^\times$ of the unique quadratic extension $L/\mathbf F_q$. Crucial for this construction is a function

$$j: \mathbf F_q^\times \to \mathbf C$$
defined by
$$j(u):=\frac 1 q \sum_{Nt=u, t \in L^\times} \psi(t+\overline t)\nu(t).$$
Here $N: L^\times \to \mathbf F_q^\times$ is the norm, and the bar denotes the action of the non-trivial element in the Galois group of the quadratic extension. Other sources refer to such an expression as a generalized Kloosterman sum.

*What is the conceptual reason behind this definition? Or, more generally, what is a conceptual explanation of such generalized Kloosterman sums?* My goal (in posing the question) is to avoid some of the manual verifications of certain formulas in loc. cit. by exhibiting the function $j$ in more structural terms.